# Read COM with a batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to read a a string from a serial port and save it into a VAR like this:

```
set /p y= < %COM%
```

No success so far.

I was able to do it by saving the string into a .txt file and read its content into a variable, but I can't do it without the .txt file, and I really need to.

```
::This works:
type %COM% > sample.txt 
set /p y= < sample.txt
del sample.txt
```

Comment: what platform? linux or windows?

Comment: sorry, windows!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`type %COM%`) do (
    set y=%%a
)
echo %y%
```

It may be a common idiom to capture command output as a variable. (similar to `var=$(command)` in `bash`)

`help for` says:

> ```
> FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (`command`) DO command [command-parameters]
> (snip)
>    usebackq        - specifies that the new semantics are in force,
>                      where a back quoted string is executed as a
>                      command and a single quoted string is a
>                      literal string command and allows the use of
>                      double quotes to quote file names in
>                      file-set.
> ```

It has several options and `help for` will be informative.

Comment: Sir, you are a genious. It worked flawless, would you mind explain it a bit to me?

Comment: @NathanAlmeida good to know it works. I've added a small explanation in my post. you may also find a lot of resources with the keywords as `capture dos variable`. BR.